# Not able to figure out why state is empty while writing unit tests in Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs

I've a react component which I'm trying to unit test via Jest.
My component looks like this:

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            expandModal: false
        };
        this.setExpandModal = this.setExpandModal.bind(this);
    }

    setExpandModal(expandModal) {
        this.setState({expandModal});
    }

    render() {
        const {expandModal} = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <div>
                    <Modal
                        show={expandModal}
                        onHide={() => this.setExpandModal(false)}
                    >
                        <Modal.Header>
                            <Modal.Title> Title </Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <div>Some body!</div>
                        </Modal.Body>

                </div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <Button id={"show-modal-button"}
                            onClick={() => this.setExpandModal(true)}
                        >Show Modal
                        </Button>   
                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

My test file:

```
it("closing modal sets state to false", function () {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}>
        <MyComponent/>
    </Provider>
    );

    const button = wrapper.find("#show-modal-button").first();
    button.simulate("click");

    const modal = wrapper.find(Modal);
    expect(modal.prop("show")).toBe(true);
    modal.invoke("onHide")();
    expect(wrapper.state("expandModal")).toBe(false);
});
```

I get an error saying that state shouldn't be null or undefined. When I log inside MyComponent it shows the state does get updated, but I'm not able to figure out why my tests aren't able to get
the updated state. I tried using wrapper.update() but that didn't help either.

Comment: You've got a typo in your `onHide` method. Did your testing uncover a bug? Also, don't assert state, it's an implementation detail, assert the outcome of state. If you change your state variable name, your test breaks, but your implementation didn't break. If your test breaks and your implementation still works, it means your test is brittle (i.e. bad).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo while putting on Stackoverflow. Thanks for the suggestion on not testing state. Any other thoughts on why this test could be failing?

Comment: Been a while since I worked with enzyme, but I'm guessing probably call [`wrapper.update()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html) after invoking?

Comment: Yup tried that as well, but that didn't help.